# How to integrate and differentiate sampled signals?

Tags: control-systems, pid

I am working on a control system which is defined by the equation.
[image]

As you can see,the equation is in continuous state.

$T_i$ = integral time and $T_d$ = differential time which are both constants and I can figure them out (Not of interest for now).

In the real life control system that I am trying to develop, I have signals sampled at regular intervals of time.

Consider them to be x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, …

e(t) = set_point - x<sub>t</sub>

x<sub>t</sub> is measured value at time t.

set_point is the desired value.

I somehow have to implement the above equation as an algorithm i.e apply the integration and differentiation in the constants (signal values that are sampled at regular interval of time ). Some references that I saw mentioned that integration and differentiation are mere addition and subtraction of the sample values over time.

Comment: Erm, well, [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions) is nothing but a weighted sum of samples... what prevents you from using a simple quadrature rule? And a [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Relation_with_derivatives) for approximating the derivative?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to get a sequence of $u_1$, $u_2$, etc., or are you looking for a numerical function for $u(t)$ based on your $x$'s?  Or something else, do you know K?  The RHS is the integration of a second order linear differential equation.  Fourier transforms have neat properties with differentiation and integration.

Comment: a lot depends on the kind of latency you need. i assume that you want to build this.